# $f(1/n)=\frac{2n}{3n+1}$, Then

Tags: complex-analysis

Given that $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is analytic, $D=\{z:|z|<1\}$, analytic at $0$ and satisfies $f(1/n)=\dfrac{2n}{3n+1}$, Then

1. $f(0)=2/3$
2. $f$ has a simple pole at $z=-3$
3. $f(3)=1/3$
4. No such $f$ exists.

   considered $g(z)=f(z)-\dfrac{2}{3+z}$ and zero set of $g$ is $\{\dfrac{1}{n}\}$ has limit point $0\in D$, so can I say $f(z)=\dfrac{2}{3+z}$. so $1$, $3$ are true for sure, for $2$ If our function were defined on $\mathbb{C}$ or a domain containing the point $-3$ then $-3$ is a simple pole thats for true, so in our case $2$ is false am I right? $4$ is false

Comment: You are right. The function is defined on the unit disc only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very poorly formulated question.

Your idea is correct, but it is possible to argue for both 2. and 3. to be either true or false. Notice that the formulation of the problem states that $f$ is defined on the unit disc.

In other words, question 2 and 3 are meaningless, since $z=-3$ and $z=3$ are outside the specified domain of definition. On the other hand a (the) function described by the conditions has a unique meromorphic extension to the entire complex plane, and for this *extension*, question 2 and 3 make sense. Strictly speaking, the extended function is **not** the $f$ described in the question, though.